# How to search for a child in a panel in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

How can I find if a particular child (item) exists in a panel using the id of the child.

Say I have a parent paned (`id = parentPanel`) and few panels as items of this parent panel. Now, I would like to search if a panel by id '`childPanel09`' is a child of parent panel.

[Possibly without using iteration]

**Note:** I am using ExtJs 3.4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to search only among direct childs of parentPanel you can use [getComponent](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Panel-method-getComponent):

```
var childPanel = Ext.getCmp('parentPanel').getComponent('childPanel09');
if (childPanel) {
  alert('yes. child exists');
}
```

If you want to search not only among direct childs but at any layer under the parentPanel you can use [find](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Panel-method-find):

```
var childPanel = Ext.getCmp('parentPanel').find('id', 'childPanel09')[0]; // [0] because find returns array
if (childPanel) {
  alert('yes. child exists');
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. Although my problem was a bit different, but your answer solved it.

Answer (score 2):

`Ext.Container.find()` (from the accepted answer) is fine [as of ExtJS 3.4](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-find) (which is what the question asked about). However, in ExtJS 4.0 and above, `find()` was removed in favour of [Ext.Container.query()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.0/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-query), which accomplishes the same thing.